# Can a TOKENIZED index field be remapped to an UNTOKENIZED field of a different name without using a computed? (LUCENE)

Tags: content-search, indexing, lucene

Having some search issues with using the "Name" field on items ("_name") I'd like to map it to another field that I can search on without having to create a custom computed field to do the mapping.

So for example I'm looking for something like this:

```
 <field fieldName="_untokenizedname" mappedFrom="_name" indexType="UNTOKENIZED" />
```

THIS IS FOR LUCENE NOT SOLR as SOLR has `copyField` and Lucene does not.

Answer (score -1):

You can try by copying the field from "name" to a new field

https://lucene.apache.org/solr/guide/6_6/copying-fields.html

This might help.

(edit:trailing character removed from url)

Comment: this only applies for Solr not lucene.